# Wait for loading of `grecaptcha` variable in selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, captcha

I am using selenium to automate submitting of a form on a website. Occasionally, I get a failed form submit due to this error.

```
0.62d2e676.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined
    at Object.reply_chat_form_submit (6.b0af483c.js:1:22012)
    ...
```

This variable `grecaptcha` is usually defined by the Google reCAPTCHA library, which is used to prevent automated submissions on forms. So, I want some kind of thing like `WebdriverWait` and `expected_conditions` which check if that variable is loaded in the webpage or not. I'm sure anyone who's familiar with the structure of reCAPTCHA library in web apps would be able to tell where to expect this variable.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution. I made my own custom-made expected condition object which is usable with selenium.

```
class JsVariableExists(object):
    """Custom-made expected condition to use with selenium"""
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable = variable

    def __call__(self, driver):
        return driver.execute_script(f"return typeof {self.variable} !== 'undefined';")
```

This expected condition can be used as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(JsVariableExists("grecaptcha"))
```

The `grecaptcha` here is the variable name that I want to exist before I attempt to submit the form.

###### Detail

For example, if you run `typeof abcd` in the javascript console in dev tools of the browser, you'll see that this will return `'undefined'`. But if you create the variable in the console using `var abc = "haha"`, then the `typeof abcd` will return `'string'`.